# TypeError: e is undefined when trying to open a Magnific popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, magnific-popup

Trying to open this popup but I get a jQuery error `TypeError: e is undefined`

```
$.magnificPopup.open(
    {
        items: {
            src: '/the-page?' + $.param(params),
            type: 'ajax'
        },
        ajax: {
            settings: {
                dataType: 'json'
            },
            cursor: 'mfp-ajax-cur',
            tError: 'The content could not be loaded.'
        },
        callbacks: function (mfpResponse) {
            console.log(mfpResponse);
            mfpResponse.data = mfpResponse.html;
        }
    }
);
```

I can see in Firebug that the json response arrived correctly. The `Loading...` message is displayed but the mfpResponse is never console.logged. The html has a single div root with the example style from the site. I need the response as json as there are other data to use. This is Firefox 26, jQuery 1.10.2 and Magnific-Popup 0.9.9.

Comment: As the posted code has no `e` variable anywhere, the issue is probably with something else ?

Comment: @adeneo It is Magnific Popup calling jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

The callback definition was wrong and the json response data is in `mfpResponse.xhr.responseJSON` so the correct code is

```
callbacks: {
    parseAjax: function (mfpResponse) {
        console.log(mfpResponse);
        mfpResponse.data = mfpResponse.xhr.responseJSON.html;
    }
}
```